# tcltk in portable R

Tags: r, portable-applications

I am using [portable R](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/) and I want to try the `sqldf` package a bit, I can load the `sqldf` package, but running a sql statement and gives me this message:

```
> sqldf("select * from BOD where Time > 4")
Loading required package: tcltk
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ...Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: NULL
  error: Tcl/Tk support files were not installed
Error: require(tcltk) is not TRUE
```

I have looked for solutions but most of them suggest me to install R, which is not possible as I am using portable R.

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the `tcltk` package may be missing from your installation.  The project page on Sourceforge that you link to contains hardly any information.  I suggest you contact the software authors for help.

Comment: Run `capabilities()` inside a running R session. See if tcl-tk is supported with your build. If it isn't, speak to the Portable R people about getting it part of the package - it is generally expected that core and recommended packages are include in R distributions (but not enforced). If it is listed in capabailities, then something is not allowing *sqldf* to find the tcl-tk libraries/functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

install R 2.13.1 for Windows, copy `~/R-2.13.1/Tcl` folder to `~\R-Portable\App\R-2.11.1` 
and 
`~/R-2.13.1/library/tcltk` folder to `~/R-Portable/App/Data/library`

I tried and it works.

Comment: This trick also works, when installing R from anaconda navigator

Answer (score 0):

See [sqldf FAQ #5](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#5._I_get_a_message_about_tcl_being_missing.)

Comment: Make sure you are using the most recent version of R and all packages involved and exit R and re-start it.  Also, what specifically did you try?

Comment: By the way, I noticed from your earlier response to yourself that you are using an old version of R and it may be that that old version of R is pulling in old versions of the packages involved so that may explain why you continue to have this problem.