# Error ".onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk'"

Tags: r, tk-toolkit, cran

I have a general question about how to effectively load any kind of external package into R. I have found that many sources detailing this information are simply insufficient, but I will leave out mentioning those respective URLs.  I have successfully loaded external packages into R before, but I am having difficulties loading the `fgui` package.

In my specific case, I cannot load the library `fgui` into R Studio. First I download directly from CRAN with the command:

```
install.packages("fgui", lib="~/Documents/R_dir")
```

This works fine for me. My working directory is set to ~/Documents/R_dir

The next command I use is:

```
library("fgui", lib.loc="~/Documents/R_dir")
```

The error I get is:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘fgui’
```

I have examined the thread "[Error when trying to load library(ggplot2) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066130/error-when-trying-to-load-libraryggplot2-in-r)" but it did not answer my question.

Please help me with any suggestions to get the package `fgui` to work properly in R Studio and feel free to address the more general issue of effectively loading external packages into R.

Comment: The error message is telling you that it couldn't load the tcltk package. Have you installed it? Can you load it?

Comment: Isn't `manipulate` the recommenend gui package for RStudio?

Comment: @joran I just tried inserting `install.packages("tcltk2", lib="~/Documents/R_dir")` before running the other commands, still same error.  Also, `install.packages("tcltk", lib="~/Documents/R_dir")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)`

Comment: @KarstenW. Generally speaking, if I wanted to create a GUI for my R code in something else besides R, let's say for instance I wanted to create a GUI in wxpython, would this be possible?

Comment: Have you noticed that that package hasn't been updated in nearly two years, the website for it doesn't appear to exist, and it claims to import a package (tcltk) that has been removed from CRAN and replaced (I presume) with tcltk2? Those all might be pretty good warning signs.

Comment: @joran http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fgui/index.html and http://www.cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fgui/fgui.pdf (update: July 2, 2014)

Comment: So we're back to not being able to install tcltk. The error message is pretty clear. And tcltk isn't on CRAN anymore. Doesn't that seem troubling?

Comment: ...what I'm trying to lead you towards is just to start Googling tcltk capabilities in R, getting, for instance, [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Where-is-the-tcltk-package-td3434915.html).

Comment: @thomas could you help me understand how a question that was asked (and aswered) in 2013 is the duplicate of one that was asked in 2014?!?!?!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`tcltk` is not a typical package. It's probably already installed on your system and it cannot be installed using the usual `install.packages` procedure because it is not on CRAN (just like the base packages that come with R, like `stats`, etc.). Also, `tcltk2` is not the same as `tcltk`; that is a package that expands upon (and depends on) the functionality of `tcltk`.

So, start with this:

```
> capabilities("tcltk")
tcltk 
 TRUE
```

If that comes back `FALSE` it means that your R was not built with tcltk support. You don't say what OS you're using, so it's a little bit difficult to help you.

That said, if you're on **Linux**, you need to rebuild R [with tcltk support](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Tcl_002fTk). This should be relatively straightforward. Basically, make sure Tcl and tk are available on your system in a standard location (something like `sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev`) and then rebuild R per usual procedures.

If you're on **Mac OS**, you're encountering the same error that [John Fox describes here in relation to Rcmdr](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html). In short, it's probably one of two things:

1. A file permission issue related to the directory where you have Tcl installed. To quote Fox: "You can verify the source of this problem by issuing the following command at the R command prompt:

   ```
   system("ls -ld /usr/local /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libtcl*")
   # ls: /usr/local/lib: Permission denied
   # ls: /usr/local/lib/libtcl*: Permission denied
   # drwx------  8 root  wheel  272 Sep 24 10:21 /usr/local
   ```

If the  output of the system command looks like the above, you should go to Terminal and do the following: `sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/local` and enter your password to change directory permissions.

2. You have an out-dated version of X-Windows. Try running Mac OS Software Update.

It may also be solvable by creating a symbolic link [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461888/rcmdr-launch-error-in-yosemite-os-x-10-10).

This should never come up on **Windows**, unless you built R from source without tcl/tk support.

Comment: The above `capabilities` command works fine for me. I am using MacOSX and looked at the link above. Indeed the `tcltk` error I get is very similar to the one posted at the bottom of that link. However, running `system("ls -ld /usr/local /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libtcl*")` returns no file permissions errors for me, and performing `sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/local` to double check and rerunning everything over again doesn't fix the issue. Typing `library(tcltk)` returns an error for me regardless, `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tcltk’`

Comment: @Thomas I know it's an old post, but... I have the error on windows. With R installed by anaconda navigator (dependencie of rpy2)

Comment: And i solved it using this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074767/tcltk-in-portable-r

Answer (score 8):

The [official installation instructions for R](https://cran.r-project.org/) say:

> Note: the use of X11 (including tcltk) requires [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) to be
>   installed since it is no longer part of OS X. Always re-install
>   XQuartz when upgrading your OS X to a new major version.

So: Simply (re)install XQuartz if you want to use the `tcltk` package in R.

Answer (score 8):

On Arch Linux, `tk` is a separate package from `tcl` and both need to be installed:

```sh
sudo pacman -S tcl tk
```

This is given that the output from `capabilities("tcltk")` with R is `TRUE` (which means your R is compiled with `tcltk` support as noted previously in the answers here, this should be the case if you installed it from the arch repos).

Answer (score 5):

1. delete the X11 file on location : /opt
2. delete the X11 on application unitiltiy
3. reinstall X11 again

Problem solved...

Answer (score 1):

For Mac-OS users:

I struggled with this problem recently and found that R-3.1.2 has a bug, which assumes that *otool* is installed when it is not.

R-3.0.0 (and later) ships with Tck/Tk 8.6.0, so you shouldn't need to install that.

Simply upgrading to a more recent version of R (3.4.2) fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and went down a rabbit hole before discovering a simple fix. If you install R from bianry it will include tcltk by default. Just run the installer with the default installation. You can get the .dmg here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest answer for Mac users:

1- Install tcl-tk using brew:

```
brew install tcl-tk
```

2- Run the following code:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/$version/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/$version/lib/libtk8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Obviously, run the second code in the terminal. Also, do not forget to type in your version in "$version" section. To check the version, go to the following directory:

/usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk