# Rcmdr launch error in Yosemite (OS X 10.10)

Tags: r, osx-yosemite, r-commander

After upgrading to OS X 10.10 Yosemite I started to receive the following error log when running my `Rcmdr` package in R using `library(Rcmdr)`:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Rcmdr'
```

Could you help me understand how to fix it?

This [mac os x troubleshooting](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html) didn't help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Execute the following in a terminal window:

```
locate libXft.2.dylib
```

or do it from an R console:

```
system("locate libXft.2.dylib")
```

On my Yosemite install it's in `/opt/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib`.

If your setup is similar, then:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11
```

should help fix this temporarily, but I'd keep looking for a Yosemite R package (since that will accommodate all the changes Apple made to the filesystem structure).

Of note: On my work Mac (Mavericks) this symlink is already there.

Comment: Thank you for your respond! Despite the .dylib is here:
/opt/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libXft.2.dylib
it works now!

Could you please explain what was the problem? What changes in file system were made? Are they for the good?

Comment: @user3651816 All of my systems are now on Yosemite so I can't easily confirm, but it looks like Apple just moved X11 from /usr to /opt, whereas R expected it to still be located in /usr. Probably a better solution, if possible, would be to update R's search path to include the correct directory (rather than this janky symlink fix), but I am a relative newb to R so I'm not quite sure myself how one would do that.

Comment: The alternative is to re-install XQuartz. Apple didn't move anything, it deleted things during the install (Apple doesn't provide X11 with OS X anymore, even as an add-on).

Comment: Well spotted! I would add that, at least in my case, the problems started when updating RStudio to version 0.98.1103. Previously I didn't experience any problem with Yosemite.

Answer (score 5):

Reinstalling XQuartz worked for me.

Comment: this also worked for me (as of 2017/08/31, macOS `10.12.6`)

Answer (score 0):

I added a symlink from /usr/X11 to /opt/X11 and this resolved the problem without the locate command.